# How to highlight Non-consecutive text in Gedit?

Tags: gedit, syntax-highlighting

Is there any short-cut/keyboard command to highlight, i.e., select, non-consecutive text in gedit?

For instance, say I want to highlight the words `there` and `text` in the previous sentence at the same time so that I can copy the information.

Comment: In what software?

Comment: I am trying to copy the text from gedit.

Comment: Do you want to *only highlight* the text (set it to different color) or *select* it?

Comment: No, not to change the color. To simply select the text. I have data that are arranged in columns in text files that I have extracted from calculation output files. I want to copy the data directly without copying anything else from the lines of the extracted data so that I can input in an excel spreadsheet. Thus, I would like to select and copy particular data that are not consecutive to speed up my process. I hope that clarifies, entirely, the situation I am having. However, I would just like to know in general.

Comment: I think that it is **impossible** to *select* multiple non-consecutive strings. But you don't need it (indeed that is useless).
If the information is big, then you'll need a script. 

We can help you with that, but I think that you should **create a new question**, because the current answer is very specific and completely different. Add exactly what you want to do (your last comment is useful) and show us the format of your file in the new question please!

Comment: So recapitulating, **you should leave this question as it is, accept the current answer, and create a new one**.

Comment: I think you could do this better by using a spreadsheet directly. While importing data, most spreadsheet programs allow you to specify delimiters to determine how the text is arranged in columns.

Comment: Maybe copy it over to (or open it with) Libre Office where you can select text, then select more by pressing ctrl-left button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sorry, only by double clicking can this work. If you can scroll the text use control+shift+arrow to highlight the word in the direction of the arrow.